# How to sum a variable based on factor?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example of my data:

```
Type <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','C','D')
Name <- c('DK', 'MO', 'OM', 'LSO', 'GOP', 'ADG','BFC','TMD')
Value <- c(3,2,5,3,6,5,7,6)
Dat <- data.frame(Type, Name,Value)
Dat
  Type Name Value
1    A   DK     3
2    A   MO     2
3    A   OM     5
4    A  LSO     3
5    B  GOP     6
6    B  ADG     5
7    C  BFC     7
8    D  TMD     6
```

What I'm trying to get is the sum of the value when Type=A. In this case, it is `13`. I found some similar examples by applying `dplyr`, but I don't need the type nor the name. Please help and thank you!

Comment: `sum(Dat$Value[Dat$Type == 'A'])`

Comment: Or, quite similarly  `sum(Dat[Dat$Type=="A","Value"])` and `sum(Dat[Dat$Type=="A",]$Value)` and `with(Dat, sum(Value[Type == 'A']))`.

Comment: With `tapply(Dat$Value,Dat$Type,sum)` you get the sum for each group (not just for `A`). There are tons of other ways of doing this.

Comment: Or this, `sum(subset(Dat,Dat$Type == 'A')$Value)` as @nicola said, there are countless ways to do this

Comment: Solved my question perfectly! Thank you all for the suggestions.

Comment: Another option with `data.table` `setDT(Dat, key="Type")["A", sum(Value)]`

Comment: @Sotos first comment  provided the best answer of the base R candidates because it's the only one that does not do unnecessary subsetting on the entire data set..

Comment: Shall we just mark as dupe: [r- How to sum a variable by group?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061), or do we think this is different because OP just wants a single level of the group?

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr you would use group_by to group each type or if you only want type A you could filter where Type == A. Then in both cases you would summarize by the sum of the value. I've shown both examples below.

```
    library(dplyr)

    Type <- c('A','A','A','A','B','B','C','D')
    Name <- c('DK', 'MO', 'OM', 'LSO', 'GOP', 'ADG','BFC','TMD')
    Value <- c(3,2,5,3,6,5,7,6)
    Dat <- data.frame(Type, Name,Value)
    Dat

    res1 <- Dat %>%
      group_by(Type) %>%
      summarize(sum(Value))
    res1
#    Source: local data frame [4 x 2]
#
#    Type sum(Value)
#  (fctr)      (dbl)
#1      A         13
#2      B         11
#3      C          7
#4      D          6

    res2 <- Dat %>%
      filter(Type == "A") %>%
      summarize(sum(Value))
    res2
#  sum(Value)
#1         13
```